# Remove all partition from USB drive

Tags: delete

On 18.04
I've made a bootable pen drive.
Now I don't need it. I want to remove the *iso9660* partition.

`sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb`

I tried to delete (it makes) but when I want to save the changes, it fails.

> Failed to write disklabel"

It isn't write protected (read-only is 0)

What else should I try?

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/usb`

Comment: @j-money In my opinion, this should be an answer, as it does not require anything that is not already installed and is desktop environment agnostic.

Answer (score 5):

The non-interactive `sfdisk` can do this from the CLI:

```
sfdisk --delete /dev/sdb
```

See `man sfdisk` for details.

Answer (score 3):

Use [gnome-disks](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-disk-utility&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). That is the tool I use to remove, create and format partition in my USB drives.

You can easily install it with the command

`sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You don't have to be running Gnome to use [gnome-disk-utility.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-disk-utility&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) It's either pre-installed or available for all flavors of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) with a graphical user interface. You can select

- 'restore to a Standard storage device', or
- 'Wipe the first mibibyte'.

There are more details at the following links to Ubuntu help wiki pages

- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) (what it does, and how to install it)
- [Postrequisites - restore the USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Postrequisites_-_restore_the_USB_stick)
- [mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

If mkusb cannot solve the problem, you can analyze it, and if you are lucky solve it, according to the following link

- [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than installing any extra software (and if you're comfortable with the command line), I would suggest using the `dd` command.

To wipe your USB fire up the gnome-terminal and type

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/usb
```

As was pointed out in the comments, you may be better off only wipe the MBR so as not to roast the USB

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<path of data drive> bs=512 count=1 seek=0
```

Edit: Again as stated in comments MBR is in fact **not** 440 bytes :facepalm:

Comment: This should work but might be an overkill. A flash drive has a limited overwrite number, so I’d [wipe the MBR only](https://superuser.com/a/533079/84807).

Comment: The whole MBR is 512 bytes It really depends what you want to remove. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254657/mbr-size-is-440-bytes-or-512-bytes